# Xamarin.iOS MPMediaItem.AssetURL is always null

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

In Xamarin.iOS, MPMediaItem.AssetURL always returns null for any item. I researched a bit, then tried to use the Objective-C handle. So I used

```html
NSUrl url = new NSUrl(item.ValueForProperty(MPMediaItem.AssetURLProperty).Handle);
```

Above code tries to get the objective-c handle of AssetURL property and then converts that to Managed representation. It works!

So, I decided to look into mono implementation. Mono has implemented it as -

```html
return this.ValueForProperty (MPMediaItem.AssetURLProperty) as NSUrl;
```

I tried this manually and it is actually returning null. So, that means Xamarin implementation is wrong. However, one thing flummoxed me. After I ran my correct code (first snippet), the second snipped doesn't return null, but correct value. What possibiliy could my first snippet have done to alter the behaviour of second snippet ?

Comment: Code snippet is for HTML / JS / CSS. You can't use it with objective-c.

Comment: That's not objective-c. However, what to use for c# ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the handle that is returned from `ValueForProperty` was not an `NSUrl` and the `as` cast makes it `null` (e.g. it could be an internal/private type).

> What possibly could my first snippet have done to alter the behaviour of second snippet ?

Simple. You created an `NSUrl` with this specific handle value. If you try to get it again the same instance will be returned (unless it was garbage collected) so we have a single managed instance representing a single native instance.

Comment: It is definitely NSUrl. It is documented as so by ios sdk. If it was not so, We could not create its managed representation as NSUrl. However, there is a caveat. ValueForProperty returns -(id). So, its actual class is not known beforehand, hence returned NSObject is not NSUrl in managed representation. If an object is NSUrl in unmanaged representation, that doesn't mean its managed NSObject is also definitele managed NSUrl.

Comment: The fact that it's documented to be a type only means it's compatible with that type (i.e. it can be something else and, when that happens, the XI runtime must deal with this). You can try a `Console.WriteLine (item.ValueForProperty(MPMediaItem.AssetURLProperty).Description);` to see more.

Also the `as` cast can take a `NSObject` and turn it into an `NSUrl` if the native object is of that type. That's how the collections (e.g. NSDictionary) are able to work.

Comment: FWIW I do get `NSUrl` instances out of `item.AssetURL` when I try this on a device, e.g. `ipod-library://item/item.m4a?id=8380231058135138167`. Can you open a bug report and give us all the version information about the software you're using + the version of iOS being used ?

Comment: I don't know what XI does to deal with compatible types. But one thing is sure, even if underlying object is NSUrl, the managed one may not be NSUrl, if XI didn't recognize the underlying object correctly. 'as' cast has nothing to do with native object. It only sees managed NSObject. It is Xamarin runtime, which works behind to make sure that types are wrapped properly. The "Descriptio' is proper ipod library url. My version is Version: 8.2.0.193 (Indie Edition)